# Use multiple ModelViewSet for a REST call

Tags: python, django, rest, design-patterns, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework's ModelViewSet. Inside "ModelViewSet-1", I need to break down a POST (create) request into 3 parts. The first part will be used by "ModelViewSet-1" and I need to delegate the other two parts to "ModelViewSet-2" and "ModelViewSet-3" respectively. Can someone suggest a workflow?

For now, I'm thinking of using python's 'requests' library, to send circular HTTP calls from 'ModelViewSet-1" to the other ModelViewSets. But that doesn't seem elegant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'delegate'? Are you just trying to modularize your code? Use mixins. If you're trying to speed things by having asynchronous tasks, look into passing off work to Celery. Otherwise, having views calling views sounds like it's going to be pretty messy.

Comment: May be this scenario will help: 

view-1 : creates instance of model-1.
view-2 : creates instance of model-2.
view-3 - does some pre-processing and creates an instance of model-1 and several instances of model-2.

client will send a request to view-3. View-3 will preprocess and use view-1 to create an instance of model-1 and use view-2 to create several instances of model-2.

Answer (score 1):

Calling other ModelViewSets is possible, but not recommended (by me). But here's how you could do it if that's what you really want to do:

```
class ViewSet3(ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        # Preproccess 
          ....

        # Call view 1 & 2
        response1 = ViewSet1.as_view({'post': 'create'})(request)
        response2 = ViewSet2.as_view({'post': 'create'})(request)
```

However, it's more likely that you just need a [custom `create`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) method on your serializer to handle creating all of the other objects, not multiple views (I assume you're using JSON).

```
class View3Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # my nested fields
    view_1_data = View2Serializer(required=False)
    view_2_data = View3Serializer(required=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        view_1_data = validated_data.pop('view_1_data', None)
        view_2_data = validated_data.pop('view_2_data', None)

        # Create my View3 object normally
        instance = View3Model.objects.create(**validated_data)

        # Create other objects with other data here
          ....

        return instance
```

Comment: That is a good workflow. Let me see if I can implement it. Thanks a lot! I'll get back to you.